# Há possíbilidade de criar frames HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou em um projeto, onde a camada de front-end está totalmente, TOTALMENTE separada da banck-end. Elas se comunicam via ajax por REST.

E nesse projeto, eu gostaria de quebrar o html, para não ficar com conteúdo duplicado. Assim como fazemos em asp.net (master.pages e usercontrols), java, php, etc. Por exemplo criando um topo/cabeçalho e um rodapé q são sempre fixos em uma pagina template, e o conteudo dessa carrega apenas o conteudo de outras páginas.

O grande problema é que preciso fazer isso utilizando somente HTML5 ou no maximo JavaScript. Até onde meus conhecimentos vão, isso não e muito possível. Tentei usar o iframe do html, mas não é muito funcional.

Alguém tem alguma idéia, ou referência de como resolver isso?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Alguma restrição em se ter, por exemplo, um <section> ou um <article> com ID definido e você carregar dados com $.ajax e populá-lo com jquery.html()?

Comment: Não tem restrição @BrunoAugusto, tem alguma referência de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O próprio manual de [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) tem exemplos, apesar de apenas um deles demonstrar o uso de um seletor quando a requisição se completera, no *done()*.

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma olhada, e espero que isso me traga solução. Os dados do que vou carregar com $.ajax, pode ser um pedaço de código html em um arquivo de texto, certo? Por exemplo menu.html

Comment: recomendo o uso de algumas bibliotecas criadas para este fim como o [knockoujs](http://www.knockoutjs.com) [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org) BackBoneJs ou EmberJs. Eles forncem Two-Way bindings entre o html e os dados do backend por javascript. Em um dos tutorias do KnockOutJs ele ensina a criar uma SinglePage Application (que é o que eu acredito você procura)

Comment: Outra coisa, você pode utilizar o ServerSide Include e ficar alterando a visibilidade dos conteúdos, se o site for todo estático

Comment: @Caputo, o site é totalmente dinamico, mas tem essa separação total. Do Java e do HTML, não é algo como jsf ou jsp. Isso que complicou minha vida. Não conheço o AngularJS, vou pesquisar a respeito e ver se me atende. Por hora consegui fazer via ajax e está suprindo minha necessidade.

Comment: @EricoSouza De casa eu posto um exemplo de uso com o KnockOutJs. Também é com Ajax, como no exemplo abaixo, mas tem alguns recursos para ficar mais fácil gerenciar o conteúdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No bruto seria mais ou menos assim, você adaptaria de acordo com o seu projeto

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="content">
        <!-- conteúdo das páginas -->
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
function pagLoad(pag) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: pag,
        success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Exemplo de chamada:**

```
pagLoad("contato.html");
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara, isso ai funcionou certinho aqui. Como não manjo muito de ajax, não fazia ideia de que era possível fazer isso. Vlw

Comment: show!! qualquer dúvida só colocar ai

Comment: Fiz como me recomendou, mas algumas vezes o conteudo importado parece não ser carregado. Já ocorreu isso contigo?